# Python: Change Color of frame root.configure(background='red') don't work

Tags: python, tkinter, background-color

I'm making a multiwindow GUI in tkinter and I want to change the backgroundcolor of the gui. I've tried multiple suggested solutions and they don't work. For example root.configure(background='red'). This doesn't work either: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/SetFramebackgroundcolor.htm

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

def loadmsg(msg):
    popupload.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("textfiler", ".txt"), ("Alla filer", ".*")))


class Dod(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "GUi")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="GUI", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))


        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Ok",
                             command=lambda: controller.label2)

        button.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        button1.pack()

root = Dod()
root.geometry("800x400")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have any code that is trying to change background colors. What's the problem? Show us what you've tried. Both of the solutions you mention in your question will work.

Comment: That's my problem. I don't know how to implement the code...

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy...

All you need to do is add a container.config() argument in the **init** function of the class Dod(tk.Tk) after the argument container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1). Then, add frame.config(bg="black") after self.frames[F]=frame inside the loop for F in (start1,start,P1,P2).[This will give black colour to all frames in the loop] 
The code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

def loadmsg(msg):
    popupload.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("textfiler",    ".txt"), ("Alla filer", ".*")))


class Dod(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "GUi")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        F1.config()

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.config(bg="black")
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="GUI", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page One",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))


        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Ok",
                         command=lambda: controller.label2)

        button.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        button1.pack()

root = Dod()
root.geometry("800x400")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Inside the StartPage.__init__ function, you call the parent init with ttk.__init__ though the class  is a descendent of tk.Frame, not ttk.Frame.  Is this valid?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7, and found that ttk.Frames do not have bg as one of their config items.  I changed those to tk.Frames and things worked until I hit the F1.config() line above, and the reference to controller.label2 in the button2 definition, which is not defined.